# Can't receive notification from GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the Android Hive [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). It was working fine before but now it's not working.

When I register my device, it gets registered and I can see registered device on my web page, but when I sent message, I can't receive it on device. Here are some messages I get when I register `GCM`:

```
03-05 12:18:09.200: E/GCMRegistrar(1008): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
03-05 12:18:09.500: E/URL(1008): > http://10.0.2.2/gcm_server_php/register.php
03-05 12:18:09.960: D/dalvikvm(1008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 248K, 11% free 5975K/6663K, paused 14ms+7ms
03-05 12:18:15.040: V/GCMRegistrar(1008): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2013-03-12 12:18:15.041
03-05 12:18:15.160: V/GCMBaseIntentService(1008): Releasing wakelock
03-05 12:23:03.830: V/GCMRegistrar(1008): Unregistering receiver
03-05 12:23:03.830: E/UnRegister Receiver Error(1008): > Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@40ff0d88
```

Comment: Are you Sure your RegId is registered to your server?

Comment: can you post your GCM android code here?

Comment: @Bhavesh yes my regID is registered.

Comment: @ChintanRathod my code is same as i have mentioned tutorial above. android hive tutorial

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you might be using older version of `gcm.jar` file. Make Sure you are Using Latest Version of `gcm.jar` file. you can get Release Notes [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/wiki/ReleaseNotes) about changes in various version of GCM.

Also for fixing this issue you can also look at [Here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/diff?path=/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.java&format=side&r=3f5dee16d86402b64251708815079a305bb9881b) to get Comparison about Various Version of `GCMBrodcaseReceiver` class.

you can get Latest Version of `gcm.jar` file from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git/gcm-client/dist).

Hope it will Help.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have 2 project, in first proyect not work, in the second yes ... I don't understand, not is problem of "jar"

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the broadcastreceiver?

```
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```