# Can't receive notification from server to android device using gcm

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218162/cant-recieve-notification-from-gcm).

I thought that downloading the newest version of gcm will work, but I was wrong. I have downloaded latest version of gcm but still I can't receive notification. I have a GOOGLE API KEY and a sender ID.

Everything is fine when I register the ID - it works fine and it shows in database, but when I try to send a message from the server to my android device, I am not getting the message from the server.

Can any one help me? I have tried some examples as well, but they aren't working. Does anyone have working example, or is my API key is not valid?

Comment: Do you get a response from Google's GCM server when you try to send the message? It would help to know whether you receive an error message or a successful response.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your server code whether it access the registration ID of registered android device.

The following link has exact explanation of GCM with simple client side code and server side code.
http://avilyne.com/?p=267